# How do I reduce the file size of videos?

Tags: compression, video-conversion, community-faq-proposed

I need to reduce the file size of some of my HD videos, since I am running out of storage space. A lower resolution is acceptable, and other methods are welcome. I would prefer a GUI solution, as I am not familiar with the command line. How can I do this?

Comment: Though this is technically off-topic, I have not voted to close, as this is a beginner question that may prove useful to others looking for a video compression solution.  I do suggest that this question be converted to community wiki, though, with a single canonical answer.

Comment: Anyone asking this question could also possibly benefit from the background information in this answer, which is written pertaining to audio but also applies to video: http://superuser.com/a/447346/144607

Comment: @DragonLord I've rephrased the question to be less about software and more about the method, as per [How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software) \@goodboy, please let us know (or edit it yourself) if you feel I have changed the question too much.

Comment: @Bob you've actually enhanced the question so that it reflects that disk  space is the issue instead of the resolution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A popular option for video conversion, including recompression to a smaller size, is the open-source [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/).  HandBrake takes full advantage of multi-core processors and can handle MP4, H.264, and Theora formats.  You can also use the [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) to convert videos to different formats or resolutions.

Comment: i have used vlc but it requires time equivalent to the length of the video @DragonLord

Comment: @goodboy every HD video will take a long time to convert as its a HD and compression will be time consuming so you have to be patient.

Comment: Appreciate the handbrake tip. For windows this now appears best-in-class

Answer (score 0):

use [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org)

use mkv as the format guides can be found on the ffmpeg site

Comment: Based on the way the question is written, the OP is probably inexperienced with video processing and should not be asked to use a command-line tool.

Comment: Also, Matroska (MKV) is merely a container format; it is possible to store extremely high quality, large-size codec data inside an MKV, so that doesn't even begin to address the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Miro Video Converter is an easy-to-use GUI application to convert videos to different formats. You can also choose a device (iPhone, Android phones, etc) and select a compatible video format.

You can get it from http://www.mirovideoconverter.com and the Mac App Store.

It is available for **Windows**:

[image]

and **Mac OS X**:

[image]